# Loop through dataframe,, perform function within selection and insert result i get: TypeError: expected non-empty vector for x

Tags: python, dataframe, regression, typeerror

I was hoping somebody can help me with this, again I am a Noob, so please be patient :). I have a large dataframe with two columns (xcolumn and ycolumn), that I would like to loop through it, select the last n numbers of rows from the current one and perform a regression. The results of the new projected Y should be inserted in the column next to the data.
This is where I am standing, I have the following function:

```py
def regression(x,y):
    model = np.polyfit(x, y, 1)
    predict = np.poly1d(model)
    projectedx = 15
    result = predict(projectedx)
    return result
```

Then I have the following loop, n is the amount of rows of data in the dataframe I would want to use to analize within my function:

```
n = 20
for i in range(1, len(df)):
    x2 = df.iloc[i:i-n, 0].values
    y2 = df.iloc[i:i-n, 2].values
    df.at[i, 'regression_result'] = regression(x2, y2)
```

I am getting the following error:

**TypeError: expected non-empty vector for x**

When I slice the data manually the function works fine....
any ideas? Many thanks!

Comment: Look at [windowing operations](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/window.html)

Comment: Thank you! I tried that but get an error when I combine it with a numpy or custom function.

Comment: Unless you provide a [minimal example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) to reproduce your issue, it's very difficult to suggest anything.